# DynamoDB PutItemOutcome#getPutItemResult() returns empty object

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm trying to run the following example from AWS Dynamo tutorial locally, [Step 3: Put, Update, and Delete an Item](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.03.html).

In my case, it is:

```
val client: AmazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient().withEndpoint("http://localhost:7777")

val dynamoDB: DynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client)

val  table: Table = dynamoDB.getTable("Catalog")

try {

    val rating: java.util.List[Float] = new java.util.LinkedList[Float]()

    rating.add(1)

    val newItem: Item = new Item().withPrimaryKey("Title", "Title here").withInt("Country", 1).
        withList("Ratings", rating)

    val outcome: PutItemOutcome = table.putItem(newItem)

    System.out.println("PutItem succeeded:\n" + outcome.getPutItemResult)

    } catch {

       case exception: Exception => System.out.println(exception.getMessage)

}
```

The output is:

> PutItem succeeded: {}

While in local DynamoDB console:

```
var params = { 
TableName: "Catalog",
Key: {
    "Title":"Title Here",
}
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  else
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Output:

> {
>     "Item": {
>       "Title": "Title Here",
>       "Ratings": [
>         1
>       ],
>       "Country": 1
>     }
>   }

Comment: What are you expecting `PutItem` to return? The second example is doing `GetItem` which is expected to return the item, but why does a `PutItem` request should return you anything?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `ReturnValues` to `ALL_OLD` in the PutItem request to get a value returned, but even then it will only have the values that were replaced.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-ReturnValues

With your code you'd need to do something like replace

```
val outcome: PutItemOutcome = table.putItem(newItem)
```

with

```
val putItemSpec: PutItemSpec = new PutItemSpec()
    .withItem(newItem)
    .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD)
val outcome: PutItemOutcome = table.putItem(putItemSpec)
```